# How to trigger code when a popover is hidden in a Safari extension?

Tags: safari, popover, safari-extension

In a Safari extension, is there a way to trigger some code when a popover is hidden?
There is the `popover` event when the popover is first shown, but I haven't found the opposite, when the popover is hidden.

I use `<progress>` elements in the popover, and they seem to be very CPU hungry, so I would like to disable them when the popover is not shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From within the popover,

```
window.onblur = function (e) {
    // do something
};
```

should do the trick.